# assigning dtype to a np.array changes the expected shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I assign a dtype to an np.array it changes the shape (it has a shape that I don't want).

But if I don't assign the dtype it has the expected shape.
How can I assign dtype without changing the shape of my np.array?
I would like 'arr_d' to be the same (with same shape) as 'arr'.

```
>>> blender = [(1, 1, 2.0), (-1, 0, -101), (1, 1, 2.0), (-1, 0, -101)]
>>> arr = np.array(blender)
>>> arr
array([[   1.,    0.,    2.],
       [  -1.,    0., -101.],
       [   1.,    1.,    2.],
       [  -1.,    1., -101.]])
>>> arr.shape
(4, 3)
>>> dtype = [('sum', 'int'), ('cc', 'int'), ('xprob', 'int')]
>>> arr_d = np.array(blender, dtype=dtype)
>>> array([( 1, 1,    2), (-1, 0, -101), ( 1, 1,    2), (-1, 0, -101)],
      dtype=[('sum', '<i8'), ('cc', '<i8'), ('xprob', '<i8')])
>>> arr_d.shape
(4,)
```

Comment: The 3 dtype fields have replaced the 3 columns.  Looks like you need to read the `structured array` doc page.

Comment: `arr_d` has 4 records, each with 3 fields.  `arr` is a (4,3) array with `float` dtype (float because of the 2.0 element).  `shape` does not "bleed" across the `dtype` boundary.